# html5 <video> element upload on server as a video file

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to upload html 5  element source data on server as a video file . Here is the  -

```
<video id="video" src="blob:http%3A//localhost/5fd2872c-fd1b-446b-ab85-e6be36c57b34"></video>
```

First i am getting video source value(blob) by its id on Javascript , then send that blob data to PHP by ajax call.

```js
var data = document.getElementById("video").src;
 $.post("upload.php",
    {
        data: vdo
    },
    function(data, status){
        alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    });

   ---------------------------
//php file
    $data = $_POST['data'];
 $imageData = base64_decode($data);
 $file = 'video.mp4'; 
 $success = file_put_contents($file, $imageData);
```

I can not upload that blob data as video on server .

What should i have to do for this on JS and PHP ?

Comment: Check your $data in PHP script, it is empty or the base64 encoded data. If base64_encoded data then, share it.

Comment: base64_decode "nZ��i�����,��{�����{�6���o�w�����\�"

base64_encode "YmxvYjpodHRwJTNBLy9sb2NhbGhvc3QvMGVlN2EwMGUtYTJlNy00Mjg1LWE1YjktMTMyZmZjNzU5YzFm"

I can create video now with 1kb size , but there is empty video

Comment: What is $imageData in your PHP script?

Comment: Do you knew the answer ! @Jitendra